# Best Way to Iterate & Extract key/value from a Map in Dart?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, hashmap

**GIVEN**

`Map<String, List<String>>` where:

- the *key* is a team code
- the *value* is list of player names.

**WHEN**

When the user selects a name, I need to output the team code by comparing to the list of players (There could be duplicate names and other things that I still haven't fully considered).

I did find something that works, but not sure if it works well when the amount of data increases.

```
//Team Map Example    
var teamMap = {
  "TeamFoo": ["Bob", "John", "Jill"],
  "TeamBar": ["Mike", "Fred"]
};

//Loop Example
teamMap.forEach((key, value) {
   if (value.indexOf(_lastName) >= 0) {
      teamName = key;
   }
});
```

Is there a better way to write this functionality to improve speed or readability?

Comment: Well, if you check depends on some state in the `value` part of your key/value pair then you cannot do better than loop though all. But I would properly change you code so you only loop until you have found you `key` unless you want to find multiple `keys` and save them into a `List`.

Comment: If this is something that you need to do frequently, then you should just build and maintain a separate `Map` mapping from a player name to a team name (or to a list of team names if duplicate player names are allowed).

Answer (score 4):

One improvement i'd make is to stop when i find the value, In case of duplicates your method is suitable since you have to iterate the whole map anyway.

In case of NO duplicates this is how i would do it.

**Code:**

```
String teamCode = teamMap.keys.firstWhere((key) => teamMap[key].contains(_lastName));
```

**Explanation:**

`teamMap.keys` => returns list of keys of the map

`teamMap[key]` => returns list of players corresponding to that key

**For every key**

check if corresponding list contains the **_lastName**
`teamMap[key].contains(_lastName));`

However, to handle duplicates i'd suggest adding "#" followed by the duplicate count. If thats not suitable for player names, than something else using your imagination to eliminate duplicates.

let me know if you face any errors.

Also, if you like visual documentation for general Map/List/Set methods [i'd recommend this page](https://www.instagram.com/buildflutter/).

Comment: Thank you so much ! This really helps improve it.

Comment: Your welcome. I'd appreciate an upvote or mark as answered, helps in answering others. Kudos !

Comment: I already tried.... This is the message I am getting -> " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" [ sorry :( ]

Comment: Oh i forgot. Thanks anyway :)